# Unwanted hex value in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, hex

I created a small python3 script as follows:

```py
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    hex_data = f.readline().split()
    with open('hexConverted', 'a') as e:
        for i in hex_data:
            print("Writing {} in file".format(i))                        #for debugging
            e.write(chr(int(i, 16)))
```

which reads a file **'f'** in the following format:

```
89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52
```

and creates a new file with the hex values as the above supplied hex. But it appends an unwanted **\xC2** at the beginning everytime.

```shell
$ hexdump -C hexConverted
00000000  c2 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a  0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44  |..PNG........IHD|
00000010  52                                                |R|
00000011
```

Even the debugging *print* command doesn't mention this hex value. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you try adding a "b" to your open to specify binary format? `open('hexConverted', 'ab')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify my comment, you need to add "b" to the open and then pass a bytes object to the write. It you don't do this, it will try to encode the file as unicode and the c2 is a special unicode code.

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    hex_data = f.readline().split()
    with open('hexConverted', 'ab') as e:
        for i in hex_data:
            print("Writing {} in file".format(i))
            e.write(int(i,16).to_bytes(1,'big'))
```